# CSS selector optimization

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I was looking into ways to optimize css performance and was wondering if their is an existing tool that converts complicated selectors to more simplistic ones.

The tool would look at all css rules and create unique single-pathed selectors that would contain all the proper attributes. It would than looked at every dom node and search for any css matches, and if something is found it would add the simplified selector to the node. The css that is rendered only contains the simplified versions and the html would still have the original classes/ids so the existing setup wouldn't break.

An exaggerated example of what I mean:

```css
#original {
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
#original .nav {
  font-size: 24px;
}
#original .nav ul {
  background: black;
}
#original .nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#original .nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}

#simplified {
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
._ranClass1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
._ranClass2 {
  background: black;
}
._ranClass3 {
  list-style-type: none;
}
._ranClass4 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="original">
  <h1>Original CSS</h1>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="_ranClass2">
      <li><a href="/">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">Link 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="simplified">
  <h1>Simplified CSS</h1>
  <div class="nav _ranClass1">
    <ul class="_ranClass2">
      <li class="_ranClass3"><a href="/" class="_ranClass4">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="_ranClass3"><a href="/" class="_ranClass4">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="_ranClass3"><a href="/" class="_ranClass4">Link 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course this would require heavy tweaking and may cause more headaches than good, but was wondering if something like this exists.

EDIT:

I am not looking at a way to write more convenient CSS, SASS/SCSS exists for that reason. I am looking for a way to optimize CSS in terms of the browser. 
EX: take the original selector

```
#original .nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

simplified too

```
._ranClass4 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

Instead of the browser looking at every 'a' node, then checking to make sure the parents match, it just matches if the node has class ._ranClass4

Comment: Have you looked into Rails standard SCSS?

Comment: Yes, however isn't SCSS simply a pre-processor that renders into plain css, it doesn't necessarily optimize it?

Comment: That's true... I thought you were aiming at reducing the length of the selectors for readibility. I now understand you're looking at performance.. misunderstood your question.

Comment: My bad, I didn't really make it clear what I am looking for. Will edit the question now.

Comment: I found this interesting: [Link](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) This isn't a tool to use, but some info on how the browser works with css. In general I agree with the part `If you aren't seeing much rendering slowness in your site, then don't worry about it, just be aware for the future.`
Also: remember that sometimes having a css line like `#menu>ul>li` is easier to read and understand without needing to find that class in the html (meaning easier to update in the future by you or anyone else working on the site).

Comment: Exactly, I have a very large project with tons of descendant selectors, some with > 7 parts to them, which in terms of performance is terrible. I am not too concerned right now, but down the line this is defiantly something that can be improved upon.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid what you're doing in your example.  Your selectors should not be too wordy, but it's also nice for them to have some level of description so you know what their intended purpose is.

You may want to read into [BEM](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) and other CSS methodologies that can help organize and speed up writing your CSS.

You're also probably looking for something like [CSSO](http://css.github.io/csso/) or another gulp/grunt task.  CSSO has a feature you expressly desired, to parse your markup and remove useless selectors from your CSS.  Be wary, if you have DOM modifiers in some JS scripts, you might run into issues where CSSO removes these selectors from your CSS because, at the time the task was run, they didn't exist in your markup.

[Here](http://publishing-project.rivendellweb.net/trimming-the-css-fat/) is a good article on other methods of CSS optimization.

Comment: Interesting, never heard of CSSO before, thanks for the link!